# Sending input to a program that accepts input via stdin

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I have shell script that triggers after it receives an input from the `stdin`. It works as follows:

```
> ./ft/ft_0 model_32 -
>
> start_task_u
```

As you see above the executable `ft_0 model_32` accepts input from the `stdin` which is denoted by `-` (where input entered is start_task_u). The user enters the input in the `stdin` and the program gets triggered. How could I do this with [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) in NodeJS?

I could start the process using spawn as follows:

```
spawn('./ft/ft_0',['model_32','-'])
```

but how could I send the input using the standard input after the program has started? I need to send `start_task_u` after the program has started and receive all the outputs that the shell script prints on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Pass config option to inherit stdin and stdout from the parent process. Please find below

```
spawn('./ft/ft_0',['model_32','-'], {
  stdio: [
    0, 
    1, 
  ]
})
```

Doc Link - https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options